# How to select preceding-sibling elements by a child's attribute in XPath

Tags: html, r, google-chrome, xpath

I am trying to select several elements on a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cory_Booker&oldid=905773879) using an XPath query.

The ones I want are all the children of the `<div>` of class "mw-parser-output" that come before the References section of the page, which begins at the `<h2>` element that is the parent of a `<span>` element with id "References"

In other words,

```
.
.
.
<!-- EVERYTHING FROM HERE -->
<div class="mw-parser-output">
  <p class="mw-empty-elt">
  </p>
.
.
.
  <ul>
.
    <li>
.
      <a href="/wiki/List_of_Yale_University_people" title="List of Yale University people">List of Yale University people</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
<!-- TO HERE, WHERE THE REFERENCES START -->
  <h2>
    <span class="mw-headline" id="References">References</span>
  </h2>
.
.
</div>
.
.
```

I have figured out out how to select the first element that I don't want with `//span[@id='References']/ancestor::h2`, and the span that I don't want `//h2/span[@id='References']`, as well as how to select all the children of "mw-parser-output" that are not that particular element `//div[@class = 'mw-parser-output']/*[not(span[@id='References']/ancestor::h2)]`.

However, it's been a challenge to use these queries to create the query that I want. For example, this XPath query does not yield results in Google Chrome `//div[@class = 'mw-parser-output’]/*[following-sibling::h2/span[@id [.eq ’References’]]]`.

I'm using Google Chrome to test these queries, but my end goal was to extract the elements using xpathSApply in R.

If anyone is/is not able to reproduce these issues or see where I've gone wrong, I'd really appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was wanting to use the `following-sibling` axis instead of `preceding-sibling`. The XPath below, which differs from the other answer only in using `following-sibling`, gives the desired result.

```
//div[@class='mw-parser-output']/*[count(following-sibling::h2//span[.='References'])>0]
```

The result is all children of the `div` of class `mw-parser-output` which precede the `h2` that is a parent of a `span` element with the id `References`.